# Snakemake: how to include config parameters in rule all

Tags: parameters, config, wildcard, snakemake

I am pretty new at Python and using Snakemake, and I am trying to use a config file to modify my parameter more easily and output them in different files, but I am stuck at the definition of the rule all with the error :

```
'expression cannot contain assignment' or 'Missing files for rule all'
```

I understand that Snakemake or expand doesn't do well with the "params." part but if I change it for example '`m_qual=config["mqual"]` and `{mlength}` in the expand part ' the file is considered missing / is not recognized later.

Can you suggest an alternative with some explication please :) ? And/or maybe some documentation a bit more advance than what is on the Snakemake tutorial page?

config.yaml

```
adapt1: 'AGAT exemple'
mlength: 15
mqual: 45
```

Snakefile

```
configfile:"config.yaml" 

print(config)

SAMPLES= ["HgSim"]

rule all:
    input:
        expand("01_fastQC/{samples}_fastqc.log",samples=SAMPLES),
expand("Resume_Stats/AR.mlength{params.m_length}.mqual{params.qual}/{samples}.settings",samples=SAMPLES,params.m_length=config["mlength"],params.m_qual=config["mqual"])

        
rule fastQC:
    input: "reads/{samples}.fq"
    output: "01_fastQC/{samples}_fastqc.log"
    shell: "fastqc {input} > {output}"


rule AdapterRemoval_se:
    input: "reads/{samples}.fq"

    output: 
        Settings="Resume_Stats/AR.mlength{params.m_length}.mqual{params.m_qual}/{samples}.settings",
        Truncated="02_AdapterRemoval_pe/mlength{params.mlength}.mqual{params.mqual}/{samples}.truncated",
        Discarded="02_AdapterRemoval_pe/mlength{params.mlength}.mqual{params.mqual}/{samples}.discarded"
    
    threads: 20   

    params:
        adapter_1=config["adapt1"],
        m_length=config["mlength"],
        m_qual=config["mqual"]
    
    shell: "AdapterRemoval --file1 {input}  --discarded {output.Discarded}  --settings {output.Settings} --output1 {output.Truncated} --adapter1 {params.adapter_1} --threads {threads} --minlength {params.m_length} --minquality {params.m_qual} --trimns --trimqualities "
```

Comment: Well in the rule all input you don't need "params." nor in the the output of the AdapterRemoval_se

Answer (score 2):

After declaring the config file with `configfile:"config.yaml"` you can access the parameters like that: `mlength = config["mlength"]`. Then having the values stored in the variable, you can access them in any pythonic way, for example using f-strings: `f"Resume_Stats/AR.mlength{mlength}..."`. Or you can simply concatenate strings: `"Resume_Stats/AR.mlength" + str(mlength) + "..."`

In case of f-strings you are facing another problem, that wildcards and parameters for `expand` need double curly braces. So the beginning of your Snakefile may look like that:

```py
configfile:"config.yaml" 

SAMPLES= ["HgSim"]

rule all:
    input:
        expand("01_fastQC/{samples}_fastqc.log", samples=SAMPLES),
        expand(f"Resume_Stats/AR.mlength{mlength}.mqual{mqual}/{{samples}}.settings", samples=SAMPLES)
```

You may still follow your approach with expanding the parameters, but you need to rename `params.m_length` into a simple identificator, e.g. `mlength`:

```py
configfile:"config.yaml" 

SAMPLES= ["HgSim"]

rule all:
    input:
        expand("01_fastQC/{samples}_fastqc.log", samples=SAMPLES),
        expand("Resume_Stats/AR.mlength{mlength}.mqual{mqual}/{samples}.settings", mlength=config["mlength"], mqual=config["mqual"], samples=SAMPLES)
```

Comment: The second option (with expand) is superior in my experience as it easily scales to when you want to include additional lengths and doesn't require modifying your filenames, which I typically put into config.  If you need skip wildcards in an expand, set `allow_missing=True` to leave unset wildcards in place.

Comment: @TroyComi, `expand` is designed for creating multiple filenames out of a single template and a set of parameters. That depends on a parameter whether it should be expandable or it always represents a single value. So both versions have their applications. Using `allow_missing` may hide errors, so there are pros and cons. Anyway, thank you for that idea.

Answer (score 1):

You can modify your script as so to use the params.

```
configfile:"config.yaml"

SAMPLES= ["HgSim"]

rule all:
   input:
     expand("01_fastQC/{samples}_fastqc.log",samples=SAMPLES),
     expand("Resume_Stats/AR.mlength{mlength}.mqual{mqual}/{samples}.settings", samples=SAMPLES, mlength=config["mlength"], mqual=config["mqual"])

rule fastQC:
    input:
        "reads/{samples}.fq"
    output:
        touch("01_fastQC/{samples}_fastqc.log")

rule AdapterRemoval_se:
    input:
        "reads/{samples}.fq"
    output:
        Settings="Resume_Stats/AR.mlength{mlength}.mqual{mqual}/{samples}.settings",
        Truncated="02_AdapterRemoval_pe/mlength{mlength}.mqual{mqual}/{samples}.truncated",
        Discarded="02_AdapterRemoval_pe/mlength{mlength}.mqual{mqual}/{samples}.discarded"
    params:
        adapt1=config["adapt1"],
        mlength=config["mlength"],
        mqual=config["mqual"]
    shell:
        """
        echo {input} {params.adapt1} {params.mlength} {params.mqual}| tee {output}
        """
```